# what type of other tests will cause an error?

Tags: java

On codingbat string-2, the question end other asks to return true if either a appears at the end of b or if b appears at the end of a. Upon finishing my code, the "other tests" is the only test with an error. What am I missing?

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
      a = a.trim();
      a = a.toLowerCase();
      b = b.trim();
      b = b.toLowerCase();
    
      if (a.indexOf(b) == -1 && b.indexOf(a) == -1)
      return false;
      else if (a.indexOf(b) == a.length()-b.length()) 
      return true;
      else if (b.indexOf(a) == b.length()-a.length())
      return true;
      else
      return false;
    }
```

["other tests" is negative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGcu9.png)

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` might appear multiple times in `a` (and vice versa). However, `indexOf` only returns the first occurrence, so your index checks can fail.

Use [`String#endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) instead.

```java
return a.endsWith(b) || b.endsWith(a);
```